# Sintaxis de SQL con variables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Estoy construyendo una base de datos en Access, y quiero ejecutar una consulta update en `vba`.

Conozco un poco la sintaxis, pero me está dando fallo.

El problema es que intento pasarle unos valores mediante dos variables, y parece que no reconoce bien esas variables.

Las variables son de tipo entero.

El error que me salta es el siguiente:

> Se ha producido el error '3075' en tiempo de ejecución:
>   error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresión de consulta 'Where TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Id_Nombre_Residuo ='

Los campos de la tabla son de tipo entero. El campo `Id_Nombre_Residuo` es clave principal.

**Alguien puede decirme donde me estoy equivocando?**

Este es el código:

```
Private mIntIdResiduo, mIntTipoIdResiduo As Integer

Private Sub cmbTipoResiduo_Click()

    Me.txtTipoResiduo.Value = DLookup("[N_Tipo_Residuo]", "TBL_Tipo_Residuo", "[Id_Tipo_Residuo] =" & Me.cmbTipoResiduo.Value)
    mIntTipoIdResiduo = Me.cmbTipoResiduo.Value

    SQL = "UPDATE TBL_Nombre_Residuos SET TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Tipo_Residuo = " & mIntTipoIdResiduo & _
    "WHERE TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Id_Nombre_Residuo =" & mIntIdResiduo

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow. ¿Cómo has declarado las variables?¿Qué errores exáctamente te están dando?

Comment: Hola David. Gracias por contestar. Las variables las he declarado al principio del formulario como Private mivariable1 As Integer. el error que está saltando es el 3075 error de sintaxis, falta operador en la expresión de consulta where

Comment: Igualmente mivariable2 la declaraste como integer? que clase de dato es Id_nombre? int ?

Comment: @Fco.Javier incluye por favor todo el código donde está la instrucción SQL e igualmente el error que has descrito en el comentario.

Comment: Por favor incluye algun mensaje de error que te este dando, que pueda dar una pista que puede estar mal.

Comment: El código completo de esta instrucción sería este.Private mIntIdResiduo, mIntIdPictograma, mIntIdTabla, _
mIntTipoIdResiduo As Integer

Comment: @Fco.Javier incluye todo el código en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Tienes que editar la pregunta e incluir todo el código completo que contenga el procedimiento de la sentencia SQL para que podamos ayudarte. Aparentemente no estás definiendo bien las variables, pero hasta que no pongas todo el código no podemos verlo con claridad.

Comment: El código completo de esta instrucción sería este. Private mIntIdResiduo
mIntTipoIdResiduo As Integer Private Sub cmbTipoResiduo_Click()

    Me.txtTipoResiduo.Value = DLookup("[N_Tipo_Residuo]", "TBL_Tipo_Residuo", "[Id_Tipo_Residuo] =" & Me.cmbTipoResiduo.Value)
    mIntTipoIdResiduo = Me.cmbTipoResiduo.Value

Comment: SQL = "UPDATE TBL_Nombre_Residuos SET TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Tipo_Residuo = " & mIntTipoIdResiduo & _
    "WHERE TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Id_Nombre_Residuo =" & mIntIdResiduo
 
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub La parte de mivariable 1 y 2 lo ponía para distinguir bien las variables. el mensaje de error es el siguiente Se ha producido el error '3075' en tiempo de ejecución: error de sintaxis (Falta operador) en la expresión de consulta Where

Comment: TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Id_Nombre_Residuo = 13' todos los campos son de tipo entero tanto los campos de la tabla como las variables.

Comment: Perdón, lo he tenido que dividir en tres partes porque no me dejaba escribirlo todo en un solo comentario

Comment: @Fco.Javier tienes que editar tu pregunta, dándole a la opción editar, y sustituir el código que has puesto parcialmente por lo que has puesto en los comentarios. Piensa que si alguien entra en la web con un problema similar al tuyo no podrá identificarlo porque el código lo has puesto en los comentarios de la pregunta, y no en la pregunta en sí.

Comment: Hola David, acabo de editarlo. Perdón, es la primera vez que pregunto aquí y no sabía muy bien como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

He conseguido solucionar el problema.

El error estaba en la sintaxis. Parece que SQL en Access no acepta muy bien el paso de parámetros por variable. 
En su lugar he cambiado las variables directamente por los objetos que almacenan los valores. 
El código quedaría así.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE TBL_Nombre_Residuos SET TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Tipo_Residuo = [Formularios]![FM_Actualizar_Residuo]![cmbTipoResiduo]" _
& "WHERE (([TBL_Nombre_Residuos]![Id_Nombre_Residuo]=[Formularios]![FM_Actualizar_Residuo]![cmbElegirResiduo]));"
```

cmbTipoResiduo es un combo box y cmbElegirResiduo es otro combo box.
El evento click funciona bien, pero parece que hay que llamar al objeto, no a una variable.

Saludos, y gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Has incluido las variables fuera del entorno del procedimiento.

Tienes un procedimiento llamado `cmbTipoResiduo_Click` que dentro de la misma no contiene ninguna declaración de variables, al estar fuera del procedimiento no tiene acceso a la misma.

Además, la declaración de `mIntIdResiduo` y `mIntTipoIdResiduo` las has hecho `privadas`, para ponérle más difícil si cabe a `cmbTipoResiduo_Click` que pueda acceder a ellas.

Para incluir dichas variables tan sólo debes tenerlas dentro del procedimiento `cmbTipoResiduo_Click`.

```
Private Sub cmbTipoResiduo_Click()

    Private mIntIdResiduo, mIntTipoIdResiduo As Integer

    Me.txtTipoResiduo.Value = DLookup("[N_Tipo_Residuo]", "TBL_Tipo_Residuo", "[Id_Tipo_Residuo] =" & Me.cmbTipoResiduo.Value)
    mIntTipoIdResiduo = Me.cmbTipoResiduo.Value

    SQL = "UPDATE TBL_Nombre_Residuos SET TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Tipo_Residuo = " & mIntTipoIdResiduo & _
    "WHERE TBL_Nombre_Residuos.Id_Nombre_Residuo =" & mIntIdResiduo

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub
```

Comment: El procedimiento cmbTipoResiduo es un combo, y al hacer cilck en la lista desplegable se debería actualizar la tabla TBL_Nombre_Residuos. He probado lo que me dices pero sigue saltado el mismo error. He probado a inicializar las variables como públicas y tampoco funciona.

Comment: @Fco.Javier el procedimiento que tienes es Click() no OnChange(). Esto quiere decir que en el momento en el que sueltas el botón del ratón se empieza a ejecutar el código. Lo más seguro es que el combo esté sin ningún valor cuando esto sucede y de ahí el error. Lo que puedes probar es a poner dicho procedimiento en un botón, no en el combo, o cambiar el método a OnChange o Change. No recuerdo como se denomina exáctamente en vba.